# FXCop violation CA1716 IdentifiersShouldNotMatchKeyword

Tags: c#, identifier, fxcop

We have recently started using FxCop on our code base and I am in the process of evaluating the problems.  One is the IdentifiersShouldNotMatchKeywords issue.  This applies to a namespace company.blah.Event, which it wants me to change to something else as event is a keyword.  [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182248.aspx) say:

When to Suppress Warnings
Do not suppress a warning from this rule. The library might not be usable in all available languages in the .NET Framework.

under what circumstances might it not be available?  Do I need to change this? I imagine that it is not going to be very popular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different languages have different keywords.  For example I can use `If` as a variable in C#, but if someone loads up the project in VB, they're screwed, any case like that can cause problems.

I'd change it, just to be safe.  I'd say you **need** to change it if anyone else is consuming your library, you can't know what language they're going to use when doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a bit of a screwy message.  It proclaims to know what the keywords will be in an as-yet unwritten language.  For all you know, a future language like BrainFart may use Acme as a keyword, and you're screwed because that happens to be your company name.

There is a notable difference between the Acme and Event keywords though.  The author of the BrainFart language will point out that you should have known about Event being a problem from running your code through FxCop.  She'll win that argument.

You'd better change it.

Comment: If you look at my example, it applies to current languages as well.  Write a library in C#...make a VB.Net project, reference that C# assembly....immediate problems using that identifier if it's a keyword.

Comment: @Nick: I don't repro that, the VB.NET compiler still treats "If" as a contextual keyword.  This compiles fine: `Dim obj2 As New CSharp.If.Class1`. But that wasn't really the point of my post.